# objects clipping really far away

Tags: camera, extrude, clipping

I have an issue where the windows for a buildings windows keep clipping but they're really far away. I tried adjusting the camera clipping length but it didn't do much. how can I fix this?

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W4x8eQ06nOAnnKZ3tGYntaeaUXFFDerU/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image: building windows clearly extruded]

Comment: are you sure that the faces are not overlapping?

Comment: Maybe your Clip End is not high enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a separate setting for clip start / clip end that's just for the 3D viewport. Press N to bring up the right side panel and go to view; at the top there should be the settings for it along with focal length.